# Prevenir page Reload on submit click

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo

aqui mi html:

```
    <form method="post" id="shoppingcart_form" class="form-horizontal">
    <input name="currency" id="currency" value="USD" type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Monto" value="<?php echo $generalTotal;?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Descripcion" value="Pack Test">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="orderid" id="orderid" placeholder="OrderId" value="<?php echo $TransactionsBookingNumber?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="documento" id="documento" placeholder="Documento" value="<?php echo $cardnetReference?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="uniqueid" id="uniqueid" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $cardnetReference?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="taxableAmount" id="taxableAmount" placeholder="" value="00.00">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="invoice" id="invoice" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $TransactionsBookingNumber?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="isFinalConsumer" id="isFinalConsumer" checked="checked">
    <input type="hidden" name="capture" id="capture" checked="checked">
    <input type="hidden" name="PWToken" id="PWToken">
    <input type="hidden" name="IsCommerceToken" id="IsCommerceToken" value="0">
    <br>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-12 text-left" style="margin:20px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success procesarbtn"  id="btnCheckout" style="margin-bottom:10px" style="font-size : 20px;">Procesar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="GBackCheckout()" style="margin-right: 5px;margin-bottom:10px" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" autocomplete="off"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Continuar comprando</button>
    </div>
    </form>
<script>

     document.getElementById("btnCheckout").addEventListener("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            PWCheckout.Bind("tokenCreated", OnTokenReceived);
                    var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
                    var currency = document.getElementById("currency").value;
                    var uniqueid = document.getElementById("uniqueid").value;
                    var trxtoken = document.getElementById("PWToken").value;
                    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                    var email = document.getElementById("emailNameChecking").value;
                    PWCheckout.SetProperties({

                    "TrxToken":trxtoken,
                    "amount": amount,
                    "Tip":000,
                    "currency":"$",
                    "capture":true,
                    "lang": "ESP",
                    "form_id": "shoppingcart_form",
                    "name": name,
                    "email": email,
                    "image": "https://myurl.com/images/logo.png",
                    "button_label": "Pagar #monto#",
                    "checkout_card": "1",
                    "autoSubmit": "true",
                    "DataDo":{"Tax":000,"Invoice":'000001'}
            });

            function OnTokenReceived(token) {

                //$("#PWTokenAux").val(token.TokenId);
                $("#modalOtToken").text(token.TokenId);
                $('#processingPurchase').modal('open');


                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#PWTokenAux").val($("#PWToken").val());

                }, 2000);


            }

        });

        PWCheckout.AddActionButton("btnCheckout");
</script>
```

El problema que presento con este codigo es el reload de la pagina, se que usa un autosubmit=true, pero necesito prevenir que me recargue la pagina , aun asi este lo hace, que puedo estar haciendo mal

Comment: podrias colocar el html del formulario.

Comment: Listo actualice mi pregunta con el html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta con esta estructura para que te asegures de quitarle el comportamiento por defecto al formulario.

```js
document.getElementById('form')
  .addEventListener('onsubmit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    // code
  )}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  ...
  <button type="submit">Continuar</button>
</form>
```

o simplemente en el html

`<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">`

Comment: onsubmit es un [Global Event Hanlder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit).
Que se puede usar com attributo `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">` como lo muestras, o definiendo una funcion en el elemento `document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {}.`.

Pero no estoy seguro de que se pueda utilizar en el `addEventListener` como lo muestras, segun los [eventos definidos en la especificacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: No hice la prueba antes de enviarlo (acepto mi error), lo que quiero es dar la idea de que en lugar que usar un evento click, puedes hacer todo desde el submit